# how to move character - trying to apply touchDown and touchUp

Tags: android, libgdx

Using the example [with the bucket](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp)  I am trying instead of using the

```
 if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
         Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
         touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
```

to use touchUp and touchDown.

So, in order to use them ,I define :

```
 Vector2    position = new Vector2();
 Vector2    velocity = new Vector2();
```

and then :

```
public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

    if (x < 800 / 2 && y > 480 / 2) {
        //here?? for left movement
    }
    if (x > 800 / 2 && y > 480 / 2) {
        //here?? for right movement
    }
    return true;

}
```

Generally , I understand that I have a position and a velocity.And I must update the position related to velocity ,but I can't figure how.

Answer (score 2):

You must update the position of your object every frame using the deltatime and the velocity vector.

Something like this(in render):

```
position.set(position.x+velocity.x*delta, position.y+velocity.y*delta);
```

And:

```
public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

    if (x < 800 / 2 && y > 480 / 2) {
        //here?? for left movement
        velocity.x = -10;
    }
    if (x > 800 / 2 && y > 480 / 2) {
        //here?? for right movement
        velocity.x = 10;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    velocity.x = 0;
}
```

Comment: :Hello , the bucket doesn't move.Maybe we should bind the bucket with position and velocity somehow?I tried as the example,to add sth like " bucket.x = position.x - 64 / 2;" but it doesn't work either.

Comment: First, delete position vector. And in my code replace all "position." with "bucket.".
Second, I see you are still newbie, so do not forget to initialize velocity correctly "Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0, 0)"

Comment: :At  bucket.set(bucket.x+velocity.x*delta, bucket.y+velocity.y*delta); it gives "The method set(Rectangle) in the type Rectangle is not applicable for the arguments (float, float)"

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was a Vector. Then do this:
bucket.x+=velocity.x*delta;
bucket.y+=velocity.y*delta;

Comment: :Still, not moving..(I removed the fist piece of code I have in my post "if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {...." ,right? )

Comment: Yes. Did you create a new input processor and setted it like this?: "Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(InputProcessor);"
refer to this if you don't know what I'm talking about :p.
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/handlingUserInput

Comment: :Yes, I have in 
   public void create() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this); and my class implements InputProcessor

Comment: Weird. Are these lines in the render method? bucket.x+=velocity.x*delta; bucket.y+=velocity.y*delta;

Comment: :yes, I have "public void render (float delta) {
   draw(delta);
   bucket.x+=velocity.x*delta; 
   bucket.y+=velocity.y*delta;
   
  }
 public void draw(float deltaTime) {
  
  
  
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   ...."

Comment: Mmm I would need to see your whole code u.u I will be back in some hours (6 a.m. here)

Comment: :Ok, thank you .When you come back send me a message (14.40 here)

Comment: :Can we start a chat and show it there?Because I don't know pastebin?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32178/discussion-between-george-and-lestat)

Comment: :Hello , I send you a message in chat.It doesn't work.Do you have other ideas about that?Thanks!

Comment: mmmmm try a bigger velocity, instead of 10, 100. instead of -10, -100.

Comment: :If you come with an idea ,let me know :) .Thanks!